# Angular 2 HTTP POST error, not showing up in Fiddler

Tags: angular, http, rxjs

I have been working with Angular 1 for about 1.5 years, I am just now trying to learn Angular 2. I have created a simple Blog app to test it out. When I try to POST to a web service, my POST is hitting an error. The bigger problem is, that the code in the catch() block is NOT executing. And the call itself is not showing up in Fiddler or the browser's Network tab, so the error is prior to any network or Web API issues. Since the catch() is failing, I have nothing to go on. Here is a snippet of my code, and a video showing the error getting swallowed. Any ideas?

https://www.screencast.com/t/ibxB9hBDYXLn

```
  insertPost(post: Post) {
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    // let jsonPost = JSON.stringify(post);

    let url = 'http://localhost:53757/api/Posts';
    return this.http
      .post(url, post, options)
      .map((response: Response) => {  // This is where the error occurs
        let ret = <string>response.json(); // This line never executes
        return ret;
      })
      .do(data => console.log(data))
      .catch((err: Response) => {  // The error is caught here, BUT...
        let details = err.json(); // This line never executes either
        console.log('Error: ' + details);
        return Observable.throw(details);
      });
    // .catch(this.handleError);

  }

  private handleError(error: Response) {
    console.error(error);
    let msg = `Error status code ${error.status} at ${error.url}`;
    return Observable.throw(msg);
  }
```

UPDATE: So I figured out part of this. It seems that this is an Observable, and so I need to subscribe to it in order for it to work. I still don't really understand the new paradigm shift from Promises. So, this works:

```
  insertPost(post: Post) {
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    let url = 'http://localhost:53757/api/Posts';
    let postResponse;

    return this.http
      .post(url, post, options)
      .map((res: Response) => res.json())
      .subscribe((res: Post) => postResponse = res);
  }
```

Now, the problem is, how do I know when this HTTP call is done so that I can call a redirect to go view the new post? In Angular 1 and promises, I could use a .then() call (from the function that called the service) so that I could then call the redirect once the post was complete. How do I make that work when using an observable?

Comment: `subscribe` is equivalent to `then`. Remove it from your `insertPost` service method and `subscribe` to the `Observable` in your component

Comment: Just like Harry said, and then performe the redirect inside the callback (subscribe)